# reference.conf vs application.conf files in Akka

Tags: scala, configuration, sbt, akka, akka-http

I am new in Akka and I am trying to understand the difference between the `reference.conf` and `application.conf` files?

What is the proper way to use them? What kind of variables should I have in each file?

Answer (score 21):

`reference.conf` is a file for library developers. All properties required by the library should be mentioned there and filled with reasonable default values when possible.

`application.conf` is a file for application developers. A developer can set values for properties used by libraries in case they are not the same as defaults.
Also he/she can declare his own properties and refer them from the code.

When `ConfigFactory.load` is called all `reference.conf` and `application.conf` files are merged into one configuration and `application.conf` has higher precedence.

Comment: So, when you want to configure the log level, some static context is better to include those variables to `application.conf`, eight?

Comment: Suppose that you willl have an answer! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978999/externalize-configuration-akka

Comment: One more clarification/confirmation: When you want to configure a thread pool or smth related with this stuff, you include these variables to `reference.conf`

Comment: If you are not building a library that will be reused in several places you don't need to touch `reference.conf` at all. Just put all properties in `application.conf`.